# Why can't update url protocol when old protocol include '+' in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Why can't update url protocol when old protocol include '+'

here is my demo test code

```js
let u = new URL( 'git+https://url-fake-hostname/zh-TW/scripts')

console.log(u)

u.protocol = 'http:';

console.assert(u.protocol !== 'git+https:', u.protocol)
```

Comment: Aaand what's wrong with this code?

Comment: @deceze just do it at nodejs. in browser u.protocol can be update, but in nodejs it can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL is a special object in Node.js, since Node.js want to make it browser-compatible.

There have two kind of method to build URL object

1. [WHATWG URL API](https://url.spec.whatwg.org) `new URL(url)` - used by web browsers
2. Legacy API `require('url').parse(url)` - Node.js specific

As [document](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_special_schemes) mentions:

> The WHATWG URL Standard considers a handful of URL protocol schemes to be special in terms of how they are parsed and serialized. When a URL is parsed using one of these special protocols, the `url.protocol` property may be changed to another special protocol but **cannot be changed to a non-special protocol**, and vice versa.

Here is some example of same case that you had met:

```js
const u = new URL('http://example.org');
u.protocol = 'https';
console.log(u.href);
// https://example.org
```

```js
const u = new URL('http://example.org');
u.protocol = 'fish';
console.log(u.href);
// http://example.org
```

You can solve this problem by calling Legacy API:

```js
const url = require('url');

let u = url.parse( 'git+https://url-fake-hostname/zh-TW/scripts')
u.protocol = 'http:';
console.log(u.protocol);// protocol: 'http:'
```

Comment: thx answer, i create https://github.com/bluelovers/ws-http/tree/master/packages/replace-url-protocol#readme for another way avoid this

Comment: Looks great! :)